# " was unexpected at this time

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I have a code that is supposed to read a big text file in groups. I have separated the problem part in a much smaller code containing only the for loop this problem occurs in. The code works in a way that it reads 100 lines, then goes out of the for loop, goes back, and skips 100 lines, reads next 100, then skips 200, reads next 100... etc etc. But there seems to be a problem with the options in the for loop. It gives me " was unexpected at this time. As in the title.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set  skipline=0
:loop
FOR /F "skip=%skipline%" %%G IN (doc1.txt) DO (
if NOT !line! GTR 100 (
    set /a line+=1
    echo line!line! %%G
) else goto :endloop
)
:endloop
set /a line=0
set /a skipline+=100
pause
goto :loop
```

I really would appreciate an answer, because I can't continue my work until I can fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MC ND indicated in his answer, the problem is that `skip` FOR option can not skip 0 lines. A way to fix this point in your code is this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set skipline=0
set "skip="
:loop
   set line=0
   FOR /F "%skip%" %%G IN (doc1.txt) DO (
      set /a line+=1
      echo line!line! %%G
      if !line! EQU 100 goto :endloop
   )
   :endloop
   set /a skipline+=100
   set "skip=skip=%skipline%"
   pause
goto :loop
```

However, you may use a simpler method that consist in redirect the file into a subroutine, so you can read the lines there via a `set /P` command placed in a `FOR /L` loop that run faster than your method. When the end of the file is reached, `set /P` set the errorlevel to 1, so this is a simple way to end the process.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :ProcessFile < doc1.txt
goto :EOF


:ProcessFile
   for /L %%i in (1,1,100) do (
      set /P "line="
      if errorlevel 1 goto endFile
      echo line%%i !line!
   )
   pause
goto ProcessFile
:endFile
exit /B
```

Comment: I like the subroutine redirection. But there is a problem in the `set /p` line read and `errorlevel` check if the input file contains any empty line.

Answer (score 3):

`for /f` will not allow you to skip 0 lines. Try with something like

```dos
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set  "skiplines=0"

:loop
    if %skipLines%==0 ( set "skip=" ) else (set "skip=skip=%skipLines%")
    set /a line=0
    (FOR /F "%skip% delims=" %%G IN (doc1.txt) DO (
        set /a "line+=1"
        echo line!line! %%G
        if !line! EQU 100 goto :endloop
    )) || goto endFile
:endloop
    set /a skipLines+=100
    pause
    goto :loop

:endFile
    echo File processed
```

- The full `skip` clause is stored in a variable depending on the number of lines to skip. If `%skipLines%` is 0, then no `skip` clause must be used.
- There is a conditional execution operator at the end of the `for` loop to test if the file has been completely processed. When the `for /f` can not read anything from the file (we are skipping all the lines) it raises errorlevel and the `goto endFile` is executed.

In any case, you should note that the `for /f` will always load all the data in the file into memory. The `skip` clause just indicates where to start to execute the code inside the `do` clause.